# King County map not displaying the boundaries correctly

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to plot the map of King County in Washington because I'm having few data points which need to be placed in the map. The following is what I used.

```
long <- c(47.5112,47.7210   ,47.3684,44)
lat <- c(-122.257, -122.319, -122.031,-120)
price <- c(287655,456355,662500,234563)

House <- data.frame(long, lat, price)

states <- map_data("state")
# west_coast <- states %>%
#   filter(region %in% c("washington"))

wa_df <- states %>%
  filter(region == "washington", subregion == 'king')



counties <- map_data("county")
wa_county <- counties %>%
  filter(region == "washington", subregion == 'king')

wa_base <-
  ggplot(data = wa_df,
         mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_point(
           data = House,
           mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat),
           color = "red",
           inherit.aes = FALSE
         ) +
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")
#geom_point(data = House, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "red")

wa_base + theme_nothing() +
  geom_polygon(data = wa_county, fill = NA, color = "black") +
  geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)  # get the state border back on top
```

The following is the map I received. I do not find that the map looks good. Please help

[image]

Comment: Where is `House` data? Also when I run `wa_df <- states %>%
  filter(region == "washington", subregion == 'king')` i get  an empty data frame!

Comment: Hi ... please kindly check now

Comment: BTW it should be `price <- as.Date(c(287655,456355,662500), origin = "1970-01-01")`. I did get 1 red and 1 black dot in the plot, so seems to be working...

Comment: Sorry Vitali. I have made a mistake. Please check now the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

I am new to R and this is my first response, but I might have found a solution to this problem. The boundaries downloaded from the maps package are not exact. You can download correct boundary data as a shapefile here: https://gis-kingcounty.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/kingcounty::king-county-political-boundary-no-waterbodies-kingco-area/explore?location=47.477749%2C-121.920728%2C9.83

Use:

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapdata)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
```

After that, read the shapefile into R and use map_data() to convert it into a data frame:

```
kc_bound <- readOGR(dsn="~/Desktop/King_County",layer="King_County_Political_Boundary_(no_waterbodies)___kingco_area")
kc_bound_df <- map_data(kc_bound)
```

Assuming that you also work on the house price prediction data set from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/harlfoxem/housesalesprediction) you can run the following code to get a plot of the houses with the King County boundary around it (df is your data frame):

```
ggplot() + geom_point(df,mapping=aes(x=long,y=lat),color="red") + geom_polygon(kc_bound_df,mapping=aes(x=long,y=lat),fill=NA, color="black")
```

See this picture for the result: [Houses in King County plotted with county boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcEmv.jpg)

Hope this helps, let me know what you think!